# Horizontal scrolling into vertical scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I've found this code that makes vertical scrolling into horizontal. How can I achieve the opposite?  Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id='first'>
   <div id='second'>
       <!-- content -->
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
#first {
   overflow:hidden;
   height:9000px;
}
#second {
width:9000px;
position:fixed;
    }
```

JS:

```
window.onscroll=function() {
   var scroll = window.scrollY;
   $('#second').css('left', '-' + scroll + 'px');
}
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zfBhK/

Answer (score 0):

**Updated code. the code now enables horizontal scrolling into vertical movement**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<style>

body{
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#first {
  /*first I set position to absolute*/
  position:absolute;
}
#second {
  position:fixed;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id='first' style="position:absolute">
  <h1>my1stContent*my1stContent*my1stContent*my1stContent*my1stContent*my1stContent*my1stContent*my1stContent*my1stContent*<h1>
    </div>
      <br><br><br>
<div id='second'>
 <h1>my2ndContent*my2ndContent*my2ndContent*my2ndContent*my2ndContent*my2ndContent*my2ndContent*my2ndContent*my2ndContent*</h1>
</div>

<script>

window.onscroll=function() {
  var scroll = window.scrollX;
  //i then modified the css by changing to 'top'
  $('#second').css('margin-top', '-' + scroll + 'px');
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**the 2nd content should now move vertically as the scrollbar is moved horizontally. if there are any questions let me know**

Comment: I am not sure if it's working properly. For starters there was a missing div (I've added it) but still it doesn't work.. :/ I am working on it though :)

Comment: code updated. check it out. let me know what you think